# Creating several indexes with the same value - shorthand

Tags: javascript, arrays, shorthand

I'm looking for a way to minimize the creation of an array where all indexes would have the same value. It might not be possible, but I would find it very handy.

Consider:

```
var layer = [];
layer['game'] = new Kinetic.Layer();
layer['navigation'] = new Kinetic.Layer();
layer['notification'] = new Kinetic.Layer();
```

(where Kinetic.Layer is an object, however I suspect that it doesn't matter)

Looking for something like:

```
var layer['game','navigation','notification'] = new Kinetic.Layer();
```

Is this even possible? It, of course, isn't truly needed - but i would find it very handy, repeating code is kinda a bad practice.

And no, I can't have one single index or variable, as theese objects will change later in my code - and they have to be declared before usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case a shorthand would NOT be the same, as all three would point to the same `Kinetic.Layer` instead of having three different Layers.

So, in your case, do NOT attempt a shorthand.

However in general, you can assign the same value to several variables like this:

```
layer['game'] = layer['navigation'] = layer['notification'] = value;
```

Side-note: You're using an array object `[]` and then assigning string keys - this isn't strictly correct, and you should be using a generic object `{}` instead.

Comment: Hmm, when thinking about it - it makes sense. Would you mind providing a basic example of correct usage (on the side-note, that is)? Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Basically, any [scalar value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_%28computing%29) can be safely assigned to multiple variables at once. Composite values (such as arrays and more generally any type of object) cannot, unless it is the desired effect to have multiple references to the object (an example might be `otherobj.linktovalue = thisobj.value = [1,2,3];`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this should work, can't remember where I've seen it but I've seen it kicking around somewhere.

```
var layer = [];
layer['game'] = layer['navigation'] = layer['notification'] = new Kinetic.Layer();
```